# How to quit an each() loop and return early from the outer function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return early from an event handler function if a certain condition is met (If the `id` selected is already in my question list.)

However I am not seeing the results that I expect.

When the condition is met I get the "I should return" message, but I am also getting the "did I still go here?" message. This is still allowing the rest of the code to execute in this function.

```
my.test.on('click', '.question-tagging .add-question-type', function() {
            var questionIds = getSelectedQuestionIds();

            console.log("questionIDs = " + questionIds);
            var currentQuestions = $.each($('.question-list .question-item'), function () {                    
                console.log("Question ID = " + $(this).find('.remove-tag').data('questionid'));
                if (questionIds == $(this).find('.remove-tag').data('questionid'))
                {
                    console.log("I should return");
                    return;
                }                    
            });

            console.log("did i still go here?");

            // more code...
});
```

Comment: Use `return false;` to break out of `each`.

Comment: That return only breaks out of the `.each`, it's not breaking out of the click event handler.

Comment: Toggle a flag value inside your `each` loop, before you return false, and then check the value of that flag afterwards to decide whether to continue with the rest of the function, or to `return` out of it at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning from `each()`, as you saw, isn't returning from the `click` handler. You can get what you want if you abandon `each()` for a simple `for` loop:

```
my.test.on('click', '.question-tagging .add-question-type', function() {
    var questionIds = getSelectedQuestionIds();

    console.log("questionIDs = " + questionIds);
    var currentQuestions = $('.question-list .question-item');

    for ( var i = 0; i < currentQuestions.length; ++i )
    {
        var q = $(currentQuestions[i]);

        console.log("Question ID = " + q.find('.remove-tag').data('questionid'));
        if (questionIds == q.find('.remove-tag').data('questionid'))
        {
            console.log("I should return");
            return;
        }                    
    }

    console.log("did i still go here?");

    // more code...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` will only stop execution of the function it's in. In your case, it will stop execution of the loop, but not the outer click handling function. You can use a boolean flag to determine if you should continue with the outer function, like this:

```
my.test.on('click', '.question-tagging .add-question-type', function() {
            var questionIds = getSelectedQuestionIds();

            console.log("questionIDs = " + questionIds);

            var shouldContinue = true; //set up a flag

            var currentQuestions = $.each($('.question-list .question-item'), function () {                    
                console.log("Question ID = " + $(this).find('.remove-tag').data('questionid'));
                if (questionIds == $(this).find('.remove-tag').data('questionid'))
                {
                    console.log("I should return");
                    shouldContinue = false; //flip the flag to false
                    return;
                }                    
            });


            if( shouldContinue ) //only continue if condition wasn't met
            {
                console.log("did i still go here?");

                // more code...
             }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `return false` to break out of `$.each` loop. However, that will only break out of the loop callback and the control will be returned to the `click` handler function.

If you whish to return early from that function as well you will need another `return` statement in the `click` handler.